video player error iOS project in flutter
Right now video type is .mp4 and this type is not working in iOS but when I changed video type .mp4 to .MOV so successfully video played

did you try other video source in iOS? for isolated the package setting problem and video file format problem.

yes, i many packages tryed from pub.dev but not working
like :
chewie, flutter_vlc_player, video_player, flick_video_player,

when i apply flutter_vlc_player package so video play successfully
but i need all contolles like video play and pause / volume high and slow / full screen / video speed exchange
but this controlles inside package not include

my_controller.value.intialize is false or local video from cache but for network video is true and working fine on iOS.
If still not working try to encode url:
String videoUrl = "your_video_url";
String encodedUrl = Uri.encodeFull(videoUrl);

i tryed encode url but not working
